# How to pass multiple images to a function in a correct way using OpenCV with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I have 2 python files and one picture:

**functions.py**

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

def imageinput(image_name_with_extension):

    img = cv2.imread(image_name_with_extension,1)
    grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow("grayscaled.jpg",grayscale)
```

my picture: **image1.jpg** 
and the next python file:
**main.py**

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
from functions import imageinput


print(imageinput(image1.jpg))
```

and the following error message:

**print(imageinput(image1.jpg)) 

NameError: name 'image1' is not defined**

This is a simplified example of my problem. In this example the functions.py make my picture grayscale and then show me the grayscaled picture in a separate window. My problem is though i have 10 picture and i want my **main.py** work like this:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
from functions import imageinput


print(imageinput(image1.jpg))
print(imageinput(image2.jpg))
print(imageinput(image3.jpg))
print(imageinput(image4.jpg))
print(imageinput(image5.jpg))
print(imageinput(image6.jpg))
print(imageinput(image7.jpg))
print(imageinput(image8.jpg))
print(imageinput(image9.jpg))
print(imageinput(image10.jpg))
```

I just want all my pictures work separately with the function i described above, but i get that error message. How can i solve this problem or what did i write wrong? 
I use the following versions: Python 3.6.0 and OpenCV 4.1.1.26

Comment: Try with `print(imageinput("image1.jpg"))`, I have changed the `image1.jpg` which python is interpreting as if you intend to access attribute `jpg` of `image1` object which are non existent in current scenario. To pass string as an argument you must enclose it inside double quotes `"your_string.str"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the image file name between quotation marks.

```py
print(imageinput('image1.jpg'))
```